# Show that $W$ is a 2 dimensional subspace or $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and find a basis for it.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 4\\ 
0 & 1 & -8\\ 
-9 & 3 & 15
\end{bmatrix}, W = \left \{ (x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}:A\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z
\end{bmatrix}^{T}=3\begin{bmatrix}
x & y & z
\end{bmatrix}^{T} \right \}$$

Show that $W$ is a 2 dimensional subspace or $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and find a basis for it.

I don't really know what exactly the question is asking.

**Attempt:**

I reduced $A$ to $A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$$\therefore  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}$$

I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: You're given a set $W$. First of all can you prove $W$ is a vector space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Notice that 
$$W=\ker (A-3I_3)$$
so $W$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ and to find the dimension there are two ways:

- by solving the system of equations given by
  $$(A-3I_3)(x,y,z)^T=0$$
- or by calculating the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and seeing the eventual multiplicity of  $3$.

Comment: Nice hint and direction!

Comment: It was just a tiny "tweak" to a already fine answer! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The condition defining $W$ indicates that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so the question is actually asking you to find the eigenspace associated with this eigenvalue. Solve the homogenous system: $A-3I=0$ to find the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda=3$...

ok, I checked and it seems $A$ has eigenvalues $3,4$ and $9$...so I cannot see how $W$ can have dimension 2.

Comment: Eigenvectors for $9$ are not in $W$.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Excuse me. you are right...

Comment: but then $W$ does not have dimension 2, so seems as if there is an error in the question.